# When to choose variables to declare as final static

Tags: java, android, static, final

I have used final and static variables as well. what i found about these variables is,

### final variable

- A final variable can only be initialized once, either via an initializer or an assignment statement.
- Unlike the value of a constant, the value of a final variable is not necessarily known at compile time.

**what variables should i declare as final-**

Most often i use those variables whose value is constant universally and can never changed, such as the value of PI.

```
public static final double PI = 3.141592653589793;
```

### static variables

- These are those variables which belongs to the class and not to object(instance).
- Static variables are initialized only once , at the start of the execution .
- A single copy to be shared by all instances of the class
- A static variable can be accessed directly by the class name and doesn’t need any object.

**what variables should i declare as final-**

Most of the time, i use those variables which i want to initialize only once and use them in the enitre class.

### When to use final static variable

Now, i came across a term `final static` in one of my database project. I found that some of the database objects or even database version were declared as statci final.

```
 static final String DATA_BASE = "BackUpDatabase.db";
    static final int DATA_BASE_VERSION = 1;
```

Now, my question is what variables should we declare as `final` or `static` or `final static`, as using either of them could have solved the issue, then wyh to use both together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
static -  Only use when a variable which is used globally 
final -  Only use when you need to declare a value as constant 

static final - Only use when a value is globally used and it is a constant.

: - Here global means across all the instances of a java class
```

Comment: +1 `Here global means across all the instances of a java class **where constant is declared**`

Answer (score 5):

Variables declared as `static final` (or vice versa) are understood to be meaningful constants, and are named in all upper-case with underscores for spaces.

An example of a commonly encountered constant is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, or `Math.PI`.

Answer (score 4):

**final** only says that value once initialized can't be changed; **static** says that the attribute belongs to Class and NOT objects.

So when you say **final static**; this means there is just one copy of variable and it can't be changed.

Answer (score 3):

**-** `static` in java means Class's member. Its shared by all the instances of the class.

**-** `final` keyword in java means, constant, but has different interpretation depending on what its being applied.

**-** When we use `static final` on a field, consider it as a Global variable.

**-** `PI` is static variable of Math Class and its directly accessed using the class name, as `Math.PI`.

**-** Use all letters in caps to define a static final variable.

**final's interpretation:**

`final variable :` Its value canNot be changed

`final method :` It canNot be overridden

`final class :` It canNot be extended

`final Parameter :` Its value canNot be changed which it receives from caller's argument

`final Object Reference Variable :` It canNot refer to any other object, other than the one its currently referring to

Answer (score 2):

Declaring variables only as static can lead to change in their values by one or more instances of a class in which it is declared.

Declaring them as static final will help you to create a CONSTANT as @Vulcan told. Only one copy exists which can be accessed anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

### Static Variable

- You can change the static variable value by calling static method
  present in same class .
- Static variable value will be same for all object created from this
  class . if we change the value then all object of that class will get
  new value ,old value will be lost.
- Value can be changed multiple times.

### Final variable

This variable value can be initialized by two way:

1. At the time of declaring the variable.
2. At the time of creating object of that class where class constructor will have `this.finalvariable = newfinalvariablevalue;`

Once initialized it can't be changed by any method (Static or non-static).

Answer (score 1):

static methods or classes are implicitly final .
Because there is only one copy of this method existing for all the objects which means that subclasses dont have access to modify the copy. 
lets say you have a method in the parent and you dont want subclasses to change this method.. just declare the parent method as a final. Here you go.

```
class Parent {

    final void myMethod() {
        //No one can change this method from subclassess 
        //compiler works efficiently because it knows that this method will not change
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
   //from this class I can use myMethod but I cannot override.
}
```